# How to connect this Gamepad?

Tags: pc, controllers, android

I recently bought a Terios T-3 Bluetooth game pad, but I am having a problem connecting the game pad to my other device. At first I had problems pairing the game pad via Bluetooth, but now I have another problem. The game pad button is supposed to flash red rapidly while connecting via Bluetooth, but my game pad is not. When I press the home button, it turned red for ~3 seconds and went off.

**[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYDDs8kdVl4)** video exactly show my problem.

I've tried connect the game pad to my PC and android, but have had no luck. The Bluetooth cannot connect.

Comment: Does this help? https://youtu.be/edB5phgdyts?t=100

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Most bluetooth devices requirr you to hold the power button till the lights change to go into sync mode.

Comment: This has been viewed over 10k times with no solution yet. I think it needs a better look.

Comment: I have the same problem that when you press the home button it just turns off and does not start flashing. All the instructions say that it should start flashing but there is no guidance for if it does not flash. At no point is the device discoverable by any bluetooth enabled devices.

Answer (score 4):

*Method 1:*

Long press the X key, press the HOME key, then signal light will flash.
Turn on Bluetooth on your Android devices then click for Bluetooth searching
When Android devices search out the Bluetooth device, click to match and connect.

*Method 2:*

Long press the Y key, press the HOME key, then signal light will flash.
Go into the Candy Game Center, click to connect the devices.
When Android devices or other Bluetooth devices search out the Bluetooth called Bluetooth Gamepad, click to match and connect.

[Source](https://www.passiongadgets.com/terios-t-3-game-controller-wireless-bluetooth/)

Comment: That's now a dead link